# Correct URL for verifying reCaptcha

Tags: java, recaptcha, captcha

I'm writing a scala backend to verify whether a user has correctly completed a captcha, but I'm unclear which URL to use. The reCaptcha [site](https://developers.google.com/recaptcha/docs/verify) tells us to use http://www.google.com/recaptcha/api/verify,
yet the JSP Java library that I am using as a model uses http://api-verify.recaptcha.net/verify

Any help would be much appreciated to figure out which of these two is correct.

Answer (score 1):

Both of them will work because `api-verify.recaptcha.net/verify` is an alias for `www.google.com/recaptcha/api/verify`.

See it for yourself:

```
me@mylaptop:~$ host api-verify.recaptcha.net
api-verify.recaptcha.net is an alias for www.l.google.com.
www.l.google.com has address 173.194.44.50
www.l.google.com has address 173.194.44.49
www.l.google.com has address 173.194.44.51
www.l.google.com has address 173.194.44.52
www.l.google.com has address 173.194.44.48
www.l.google.com has IPv6 address 2a00:1450:4016:803::1012
```

Most probably, this is beacuse reCaptcha was acquired by Google, but they did not want to force all people already using it to update their code. Apart from that, **the latter is better because it allows to use a SSL encrypted connection.**

Comment: It seems like the old url `api-verify.recaptcha.net/verify` does not work anymore.

Answer (score 0):

This question and answer seems to be too old. Ten years later, the correct url to verify is [www.google.com/recaptcha/api/siteverify](https://www.google.com/recaptcha/api/siteverify). You can check this [here](https://developers.google.com/recaptcha/docs/verify).

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/35499453)